# Remove extra characters from thread script

Tags: html, ruby

I've got a ruby script which check microservices version from each microservice API. I try to run this with bamboo and return the result as a html table.

```
...
h = {}
threads = []
service = data_hash.keys
service.each do |microservice|
threads << Thread.new do
thread_id = Thread.current.object_id.to_s(36)
begin
h[thread_id] = ""
port = data_hash["#{microservice}"]['port']

 nodes = "knife search 'chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#   

 {microservice}' -i 2>&1 | tail -n 2"
 node = %x[ #{nodes} ].split 
 node.each do |n|
   h[thread_id] << "\n<html><body><h4> Node: #{n} </h4></body></html>\n"
   uri = URI("http://#{n}:#{port}/service-version")
   res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
   status = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
   data_hash = JSON.parse(status)
   name = data_hash['name']
   version = data_hash['version']
   h[thread_id] << "<table><tr><th> #{name}:#{version} </th></tr></table>" 
   end

  rescue => e
    h[thread_id] << "ReadTimeout Error" 
    next 
  end
 end
 end

threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end

ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)
puts h.to_a
```

The issue is that I want to output name and version into a html table and if I put threads it generates some random characters between each line:

```
<table><tr><th> microservice1:2.10.3 </th></tr></table>
bjfsw
<table><tr><th> microservice2:2.10.8 </th></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *random characters* are the keys of the hash generated with `to_s(36)`.

Replace the `puts h.to_a` with something like

```
puts h.values.join("\n")
```

And you will only see the data and not the keys.

You can use `kernel#p h` or `puts h.inspect` to see this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, any idea how can I set the output into a html table facing the fact that we have a loop ?